# Convert dataframe where row values contain desired column names (spread doesn't work)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data in the following format:

```
> ex_df
  order       country
1     1     Argentina
2     2     Argentina
3     1       Denmark
4     2 United States
5     1 United States
6     2 United States
```

I need to convert it to the following format, where the relationship in  `ex_df$order (1,2)` is maintained in two new columns (first, second):

```
# Desired data.frame:
            first          second
1       Argentina       Argentina
2         Denmark   United States
3   United States   United States
```

I haven't had luck with `spread` or `dcast`. `spread` returns an error about duplicate identifiers and `dcast` aggregates the data depending on the formula used.

```
> dput(ex_df)
structure(list(order = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), country = c("Argentina", "Argentina", "Denmark", "United States", "United States", "United States")), .Names = c("order", "country"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `unstack` from `base R`

```
unstack(ex_df, country~order)
```

Comment: Ugh, I figured it would be simple! I had tried unstack but I missed something. Thank you!!